Show $(n+1)^{r+1}-(n+1)=\sum_{k=1}^{r} \binom{r+1}{k}S_{r+1-k}(n)$ for $S_r(n)=\sum_{k=1}^{n} k^r$
Let:
$$S_r\left(n\right)=1^r+2^r+\ldots+n^r$$
for all $n,r\in\mathbb{N}_+$.
Show that:
$$\left(n+1\right)^{r+1}-\left(n+1\right)=\binom{r+1}{1}S_r\left(n\right)+\binom{r+1}{2}S_{r-1}\left(n\right)+\dots+\binom{r+1}{r}S_1\left(n\right)$$
My attempt - Induction for $r$ ($n$-const):
$r=1$:
$$L=\left(n+1\right)^{2}-\left(n+1\right)=n^2+n$$
$$P=\binom{2}{1}S_1\left(n\right)=2\cdot\left(1^1+2^1+\ldots+n^1\right)=2\cdot \frac{1+n}{2}\cdot n=n^2+n$$
Say the equation is correct for some $r\in\mathbb{N}_{+}$. For $r+1$:
$$\binom{r+2}{1}S_r\left(n\right)+\binom{r+2}{2}S_{r-1}\left(n\right)+\dots+\binom{r+2}{r+1}S_1\left(n\right)=$$
$$\left[\binom{r+1}{1}+\binom{r+1}{0}\right]S_{r+1}\left(n\right)+\left[\binom{r+1}{2}+\binom{r+1}{1}\right]S_{r}\left(n\right)+\ldots+\left[\binom{r+1}{r+1}+\binom{r+1}{r}\right]S_{1}\left(n\right)=$$
$$\left[r+2\right]S_{r+1}\left(n\right)+\left[\binom{r+1}{2}S_r\left(n\right)+\ldots+\binom{r+1}{r+1}S_1\left(n\right)\right]+\left[\binom{r+1}{1}S_r\left(n\right)+\ldots+\binom{r+1}{r}S_1\left(n\right)\right]=$$
$$\left(r+2\right)S_{r+1}+\left[\binom{r+1}{2}S_r\left(n\right)+\ldots+\binom{r+1}{r+1}S_1\left(n\right)\right]+\left(n+1\right)^{r+1}-\left(n+1\right)$$
but I have no idea for the middle bracket.

Without induction (using a "telescoping" sum):
$$
\color{blue}{(n+1)^{r+1}}-(n+\color{blue}{1})=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\big(\color{blue}{(k+1)^{r+1}-k^{r+1}}-1\big)
\\=\sum_{k=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^r\binom{r+1}{j}k^{\color{gray}{r+1-}j}=\sum_{j=1}^r\binom{r+1}{j}S_{\color{gray}{r+1-}j}(n).
$$
If one insists on induction, better try it on $n$...

I was trying both ways of induction (on $n$ I got stuck earlier). Thanks
